# No Bone or Alpha Animations in .glb

Tags: animation, bones, transparency

Why won't my exported .glb keep the bone keyframe animation and alpha keyframe animation? Yet, I translated an object and that carried over to the .glb animation

Comment: I used the "Location, Rotation, and Scale" keyframes for the bones. Also, I translated some objects that used alpha, but they don't appear in the .glb (probably cause they start at zero alpha. They probably translate, but are still invisible even though they should appear).

Comment: Don't know why your bone animation doesn't work, but glTF doesn't support animation of material properties like alpha. Only object/bone LocRotScale, and shapekey values.